# Google Sheet import historical prices

Tags: google-sheets-api

I was using Google finance to get historical stock price but similar to Yahoo it seems to have stopped working earlier this month.

So now I just want to import from a website. I am using the following import function in my google sheet to get the last 3 months of price history for stocks from the nasdaq website.  But now I want more data.  Their website offers 10 years of data. Can anyone help me alter my function to add a timeframe?

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/"&C5&"/historical","table")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mixing your query with import range function as also suggested in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/qV3Mgf-Ljzk).

You can add [`conditionType`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#conditiontype) or [`conditionValue`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#conditionvalue) with date values in your query.

See [Collection: spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) for more information.